# Using strategy to create subclasses from superclasses

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have a C#/OO/Design related question.

I am redesigning an old system that was ported to C#. We are refactoring the system to make it more simple and more object oriented.

In this system we have various objects related to our business domain - Folder, Document, User, Appointment, Task, etc. All of these objects inherit from a base object called, believe it or not, BaseObject:

```
public class BaseObject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This object is not abstract because we actually instantiate it for some simple lists.

We also have our own Generic list:

```
public class CustomList<T> : IENumerable<T> where T : BaseObject {
    //... several properties and methods

    }
}
```

My questions is this: I have many objects that inherit from BaseObject. For example, I can create a `CustomList<User>` because `User : BaseObject`.

However, many of my user controls return `CustomList<BaseObject>`, simply because that is what most list-based user controls CAN return: they know each object's name because that's what they display, and they use its Id as a key.

So, I would like to be able to add the items from a `CustomList<BaseObject>` to any `CustomList<T>`. I want to be able to add objects, not just construct a new list.

But because I can't just cast from a superclass (BaseObject) to a subclass (e.g. User), I was thinking about implemeting the following method inside `CustomList<T>`:

```
public void AddRangeOfBaseObjects(IEnumerable<BaseObject> items, Func<BaseObject, T> constructor)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var newObject = constructor(item);
            Add(newObject);
        }
    }
```

Or in other words, if a class needs to create a CustomList from CustomList, it needs to supply both the CustomList and a method saying how to construct each new instance of T from BaseObject, and how to initialize its other members which BaseObject doesn't know.

I believe this is similar to a Strategy pattern. Of course the method itself hardly has any code, but due to the ubiquity of this action, it is still shorter to design it like this.

The question is - is this good design? Is there a better pattern for handling this situation of moving simplified version of objects from the UI into actual objects?

Comment: What you are doing is more like a function-programming pattern :) Basically you have implemented a *map* function. Have you considered using Linq? Like ```items.Select(constructor).ToList()```

Comment: And for me your ```AddRangeOfBaseObjects(IEnumerable<BaseObject> items, Func<BaseObject, T> constructor)``` is a simple and clean way for what you want to do. It´s functional which is (nearly) always good. And nowadays people tend to say it´s better than OOP

Comment: Hey @MuraadNofal - thanks for the comment. I am new to Linq and I didn't even think about that option. That actually sounds pretty good!

Comment: Linq is great and powerful :) I´v posted an example because with ```items.Select(constructor).ToList()``` you would return a normal ```List<T>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bascially you have implemented some kind of functional *map* function similar to Linq´s `Select` function. Nowadays lots of people favour the functional style over plain old OOP. Your `AddRangeOfBaseObjects(IEnumerable<BaseObject> items, Func<BaseObject, T> constructor)` is a simple and clean way for what you want to do.

Another way using Linq could be

```
public static CustomList<T> ToCustomList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    where T : BaseObject
{
    var customList = new CustomList<T>();
    foreach(var item in items)
        customList.Add(item);
}
```

and then use it like

```
IEnumerable<BaseObject> items = ...;
Func<BaseObject, T> constructor = ...;

// Usage would be
CustomList<T> customItems = 
    (from i in items
     select constructor).ToCustomList();

// or
CustomList<T> customItems = items.Select(constructor).ToCustomList();
```

Without creating a new list

```
public void AddRangeOfBaseObjects(IEnumerable<BaseObject> items, Func<BaseObject, T> constructor)
{
    // AddRange from List<T>
    AddRange(items.Select(constructor);
}
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked, it's conversion of list while OP is trying to have Add function so that derived type list can add base object.

Comment: You are somehow right. But i think i´v answered the question if this is a good design.  Also isn´t it a "convert and add" function?

Comment: uhh!! I missed that from your comment. +1.

Comment: Yeah and i´v edited my answer based on your comment to show an example that is using Linq but without creating a new CustomList<T>.